# How can allowed element values depend on other element values in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a following task (in simple version):  Describe in XSD temperatures. There are min, max and default values.  Default should be placed inside of min...max values. How to describe these things with XSD?

**I mean:**

```
Min_Set_Temp [ Integer between 0 and 1000 ]
Max Set Temp [ Integer between 0 and 1000 ]
Default_Set_Temp [ Integer between Min Set Temp and Max Set Temp]
```

**XSD start:**

```
<xs:simpleType name="tSetTemperature">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="1000"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="Bake">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MinSetTemp" type="tSetTemperature"/>
        <xs:element name="MaxSetTemp" type="tSetTemperature"/>
        <xs:element name="DefaultTemp" type="tSetTemperature"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.

### XSD 1.1

Possible using `xs:assert`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:simpleType name="tSetTemperature">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="1000"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="Bake">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MinSetTemp" type="tSetTemperature"/>
        <xs:element name="MaxSetTemp" type="tSetTemperature"/>
        <xs:element name="DefaultTemp" type="tSetTemperature"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="DefaultTemp = MinSetTemp to MaxSetTemp"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```